# Shorthand Way of Conditional Assignments

Tags: c, optimization, ternary-operator

Is there a shorthand way of writing equivalent code to:

```
if (variable > max){
    variable = max;
}else if (variable < -max){
    variable = -max;
}
```

I know I can use ternary operators to get code like this:

```
variable = variable > max ? max : variable;
variable = variable < -max ? -max : variable;
```

### Question:

But is there an even shorter version of this code?

Note: Not nested ternary operators, either.

P.S.: This isn't necessarily a language-specific question, but I'm writing my code in C so I'd like to have answers that can work in that language.

Comment: you want to make C Coding even more terse?

Comment: BTW - ternary operators are syntactic sugar

Comment: IMHO, the original version is better than the ternaries. It makes the conditions you care about very clear. And it doesn't do the assignment at all if the variable is outside the two ranges.

Comment: one way of writing this would be to use the common `MAX` and `MIN` macros and write: `variable = MIN(max, variable); variable = MAX(-max, variable);`.  I agree that the original version is best though (make it a macro or inline function if you'll be using it often)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use this construct:

```
if (abs(variable) > max) {
    variable = sgn(variable) * max;
}
```

There is no `sgn(x)` function in standard C library, but it is easy enough to implement it using arithmetic operations:

```
#define sgn(x) (((x) > 0) - ((x) < 0))
```

Here is an working example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define sgn(x) (((x) > 0) - ((x) < 0))

int main(void)
{
    int variable = -100, max = 20;

    if (abs(variable) > max) {
        variable = sgn(variable) * max;
    }
    printf("%d\n", variable);

    return 0;
}
```

Note, that it will not work for `INT_MIN` on systems, that use [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement) representation, because `-INT_MIN` cannot be represented as `int` (kudos for @M.M).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for

Comment: @Michael: Of course this will run *much* slower than the original code, which can be implemented using a comparison followed by a couple of conditional move instructions. It's always better to write readable code and trust the compiler to optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

You can nest conditional operators:

```
variable = variable > max ? max : (variable < -max ? -max : variable);
```

IMHO this is almost unreadable, so I don't recommend it.